# Sprint velocity in dashboard to include story points at Task level as well as User Story

Tags: azure-devops, devops

We have created a custom Agile process and added the Story Points field to the Task work item.

Our reasoning for this is that if we have a user story that is made up of many tasks assigned to multiple team members, we want to estimate tasks in story points rather than hours.

However, when looking at the Velocity widget, we only have a choice to include the backlog at Epic, Feature or Story level. So if my story has 0 points but I have 20 points across the child tasks, the velocity widget won't include story points from any of our closed tasks.

Is there a clever way for Velocity to capture closed points for User Stories and Tasks?  Is there an extension that will do this?  The only workaround is to create a user story for smaller pieces of work but then these become technical stories such as write document, review document, create web page, etc rather than a legitimate customer requirement.